# Condition doesn't support the nested "if" element in Ant-contrib

Tags: ant-contrib

Goal: If software version is 1.1, then run target runA, else runB. 
Actually, there are many targets which needs to be run based on software version. Below is a simpler extract of the Ant xml file.

```
<property name="Version" value="" />
<target name="checksoftwareversion1.1">
    <condition property="version1.1">
        <if>
            <endswith string="${Version}" with="1.1" />
            <then>
                <echo message="Version is ${Version}" />
            </then>
        </if>
    </condition>
</target>
 <target name="checksoftwareversion1.2">
    <condition property="version1.2">
        <if>
            <endswith string="${Version}" with="1.2" />
            <then>
                <echo message="Version is ${Version}" />
            </then>
        </if>
    </condition>
</target>

<target name="runA" if="version1.1">
</target>
<target name="runB" if="version1.2">
</target>
```

Getting an exception: condition doesn't support the nested "if" element.
Any clue on how to solving this or may be a better approach..
Thanks